# Default location for static /usr/local data

Tags: files, filesystem, backup

I know that UNIX standard has rules for static and variable data. For example, `/opt` is for static data, `/var/opt` is for variable application data. I've made script to perform some backups, and I've put it in the `/usr/local/sbin` and accordingly I've decided to store backups in `/var/local/{my-script-name}/backups`. However, my script uses external file which is basically exclusion/inclusion list. At the moment I'm storing it in `~/.backup`, but it makes me uneasy to store it under the users home. Where is the best place to put such a list? `/etc/local` (although there is not `local` sub-directory there)?

Comment: I'd use either `/etc/{my-script}.conf` or `/etc/{my-script}.d/*.conf` (or both). See also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Comment: Thanks `/etc/{my-script}.d/*.conf` sounds like a good place!